# Finding PHP script that is outputting to PHP error log

Tags: php, logging, error-logging

I have web server running drupal, out of the box PHP software and custom PHP software. One of the developers has added some sort of logging call somewhere that is filling up the PHP error log with useless messages and I want to remove this logging call. How can I find what is causing these messages in the log?

Comment: The easiest solution will be take the text from `log` and search it inside drupal project. And after finding the call remove it.

Comment: try to check if you logs include the file where the error_log script is being executed.

Comment: I suggest to download all files first and then search for 'log' as mentioned and find the file

Comment: @YogeshSuthar unforunately the logged text is of an empty array. So its probably some code like error_log(print_r($var)) but I tried grepping for that already :(